# How to run Unity 8 on Ubuntu inside of VirtualBox?

Tags: unity, virtualbox, unity8

Like the title suggest is there anyway?

I tried to run Unity 8 on Ubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox with the Guest Additions installed.  When I login into the Unity 8 session from LightDM it's just loads a black screen then its log me out or freezes.  I also install Unity 8 though these commands:

```
sudo apt install unity8-desktop-session-mir
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ci-train-ppa-service/stable-phone-overlay
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Maybe I miss something to install, but when I tried to run Unity 8 in a terminal on top of Unity 7, I get the same thing.  However, I get this output:

```
mathcubes@Ubuntu-VM:~$ unity8
Mode argument was not provided or was set to an illegal value. Using default value of --mode= "full-greeter"
file:///usr/share/unity8//OrientedShell.qml:21:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module "Unity.Screens": Cannot load library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Unity/Screens/libunityscreensplugin.so: (libqpa-mirserver.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) 
     import Unity.Screens 0.1 
 ^
```

Could I run Unity 8?  Is it compatible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't run neither mir nor wayland on virtualbox. Maybe in the future... See also the links: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/3v2tof/unity_8_in_virtualbox/, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mir/+bug/1366805, https://bugs.launchpad.net/mir/+bug/1118903.

**EDIT(2017-13-01):** You can run wayland inside virtualbox now. I have successfully launched a plasma wayland session on KDE Neon Developer Edition Git Unstable with virtualbox 5.1.12. I'm not sure about Mir. I will have to test some ubuntu 17.04 Alpha release to find out.